# How to add X-header to outgoing mail with LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotusscript

I am looking for the Lotus Script which would add X-header to the outgoing e-mail if it has particular item in the list. The item value is set from the custom checkbox, added to one of templates. I also would like to know where to add this script in designer view (querysend event?). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the Domino server, you can configure it to include certain Notes items as x-headers on outgoing mail.

Check out **Always send the following Notes items in headers** on [Setting advanced outbound MIME options](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/5eda03c647f879c285256c1d00396051?OpenDocument) .

Answer (score 0):

You can set MIME headers using the `CreateHeader` method of `NotesMIMEEntity`.  I've only ever used this when constructing a complete email programmatically in an agent, so not sure where to hook that into a document created from the client.  The post save event should give you a document you can convert to MIME and then add the header, but it's likely to be a little fiddly.  You'll have to try it out.

Comment: I did play with NotesMIMEEntity class and it does the job, but only on postsend event, which is too late. Of cause I am not going to create my own message just to add one more header, this is not an option too. 
What I am looking for is may be to set some "special" document item on querysend event which will be translated into the message header, or change well known header (ex. X-Mailer, which is $Mailer item). But looks like I cannot access headers at this time or I am doing something wrong.
Thanks for replay anyway. Still looking for advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you create an notes item, then you can use the "Always send the following Notes items in headers", ie $MyNotesItem will become X-MyNotesItem